# PHP executing for root, but not for other users (apache2 virtual)

Tags: apache2, php

So I've got a site set up in `/var/www` owned by root that can run PHP with no problems.

I've created a user, added `www-data` to that usergroup, and set up a virtual site pointing to `/home/user/public_html`. I successfully browse to the domain associated with that virtual site and it loads HTML from there with no problems.

But, when I created `index.php` and put in some simple php (`<?php echo '<h1>test</h1>'; ?>`), it shows the php source code.

**PHP in the root-owned site works fine; PHP in the user-owned site shows source.**

So I know php is working with apache2, just not when the user is involved.

Does PHP run as something other than www-data? So do I need to add some other user to my user's group like I did with `www-data`?

Does that make sense? Thanks for help in advance... I'm slowly learning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default php is explicitly disabled for /home/*/public_html. To change this on ubuntu 14.04,

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo cp php5.conf my-php5.conf
sudo rm php5.conf
```

and edit my-php5.conf by changing the lines

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
   <Directory /home/*/public_html>
      php_admin_flag engine Off
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
   <Directory /home/*/public_html>
      # php_admin_flag engine Off
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

then restart apache with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

These commands may need some changes for other versions of ubuntu.

Comment: And it's even explained in the conf file. Thank you very very much. My google-fu failed me on this one. Thanks! <3

Comment: Sorry I can't vote you yet - not enough rep. :(